# Angular $http.get() is decoding '.' . Is this by design?

Tags: angularjs

It appears that angular's $http service is decoding the '.' character?
 If I run this code:

```
var arg = test.param;
var result = arg.replace(/\./g, '%2E');
return $http.get('/api/test/get/' + result;
```

I can see a http request to /api/test/test.param 
what I wanted was a request to /api/test/test%2Eparam

Is this by design?
Is there a way around it?

Comment: They should be equivalent, so if you’re looking for a way around it, you perhaps ought to be fixing the API instead.

Comment: According to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt rfc1738, characters may be encoded if they have special meaning within a URL scheme, and that the characters ";", "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may be reserved within a scheme.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at changing the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is by design. As Will Palmer points out in the comment above:

> According to ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt rfc1738, characters may be
>   encoded if they have special meaning within a URL scheme, and that the
>   characters ";", "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters
>   which may be reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other
>   characters may be reserved within a scheme.

Thanks Will.